# Android streaming data acquisition and plotting: How to pass streaming data from data acquisition activity to plotting/graphing activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, streaming

Background: I am developing an Android application with Eclipse that has several activities and uses intents to start them (does that make sense?). I have programmed a Data Acquisition activity to start a Plotting activity using the Options Menu. Right now it works to some degree. The Data Acquisition activity acquires data and quickly scrolls it across the screen continuously. Then from the Options Menu I can start the Plotting activity which plots some "made up" data like a sine wave.

Problem: How can I feed the data that is continuously coming from the Data Acquisition activity into the Plotting activity? I don't think putExtra() is the right way to do this since the data is coming continuously. I need some suggestions where to look for a solution. StackOverflow is showing there are no questions/answers about Android streaming data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only one activity ever runs at a time, it's not possible for them to transfer data between each other at the same time. To do this, you'll need to write a `Service` that acquires the data. This data could then be stored as a file, or in an sqlite database, and read by the graphing activity.

Comment: Does a thread a qualify as a service? Because my Data Acqusition activity continues to collect data even when I am running my Plotting activity.

Comment: @Jodes I am familiar with sockets in C. My Android app already has some kind of background thread/service/process that continues to run while I have started my plotting activity from the Options Menu. Why can't I use a socket in the background to broadcast data on a well known port which my plotting activity can listen on? Or is this approach deprecated in favor of an Android based approach?

Comment: @Jodes someone else also suggested to use a Handler. I don't know how it differs from Service but little by little I am getting a Handler to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Jodes I understand only one activity runs at a time. That's not my problem. There is a background thread created by a Bluetooth activity which provides an update() method that continually calls append(). I want to plot the data that is passed to append(). How do I do that? I wrote a static plotData() method in my Plot activity that leverages the background thread update() method just fine. But people have told me that a static method is not a good solution. Why?

Comment: It's not a good solution because it relies on undocumented behaviour of android. It will produce unexpected results, which is why people can't help you, you're exploring uncharted territory by ignoring the lifecycle of activities, it is the android OS that coordinates things, so you have to code activities to interact in the way google intended.